# How to convert raw data into zip file in php using CURL?

Tags: php, curl, zip, php-curl

I am using php Curl to get zip file but getting the raw data like

[image]

How to convert that data into zip file I have tried this

```
$url = "https://wordpress.org/latest.zip"; // URL of what you wan to download
$zipFile = "wordpress.zip"; // Rename .zip file
$extractDir = "extracted"; // Name of the directory where files are extracted
$zipResource = fopen($zipFile, "w");

// Get The Zip File From Server
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $zipResource);

$page = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$page) {
    echo "Error :- ".curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

/* Open the Zip file */
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$extractPath = $extractDir;

if($zip->open($zipFile) != "true"){
    echo "Error :- Unable to open the Zip File";
} 

/* Extract Zip File */
$zip->extractTo($extractPath);
$zip->close();

die('Your file was downloaded and extracted, go check.');
```

How to convert that raw data into zip file.

I have received that error ** ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object**

Comment: You don't have to convert anything, that *is* a zip file. Check the return value of your call to `fopen()` -- it might be failing.

Comment: Just receive exec ($page) and write to a binary file.

Comment: You should be mentioning errors in your questions. You have options to prep curl on return results format.

Comment: Updated my error in question please check.

Comment: Your `ZipArchive` class could be suspect. The server may not have even returned the whole file. Need more debugging details on this one. The zip could have already been corrupt for example.

Comment: means it doesn't find ZipArchive class to execute zip function?

Comment: ZipArchive is reporting the exception. Meaning like you have some problems, authors of ZipArchive may have a bug. Is possible right? But beyond that your test case zip file could already be corrupt.

Comment: Have you tried other zip files or this one?

Comment: no i have tried one more it has the same issue show the data on screen but not created any zip @GetSet

Comment: Then its the lib. This `ZipArchive` is flawed. Not an impossible conclusion.  You could switch libraries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220814/discussion-between-prits-and-getset).

Answer (score 0):

It has some permission issue if i put that file in a folder and make its permission 777 it works perfectly and download the data.